# Which mobile VPN type, of IPSec, SSL/TLS, and SSH, would be better for travelling workers?

Tags: security, vpn, cryptography, point-to-site-vpn, network-security

Not too sure on the specifics of each that would make one better for travelling.

Comment: Which of ice cream, beach, swimming pool, and cultural attractions would be better for someone on a holiday trip? You can't compare things that are used for different purposes and put them in order without specifying the exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be wanting a TLS VPN, so the remote worker has access to your local subnet. Also look into L2TP VPN. UNIFI USG makes this very easy to set up.